# Como criar um servidor para bower privado?

Tags: bower

Tenho diversos pacotes para frontend desenvolvidos por minha equipe, todos estes pacotes são privados e não posso registra-los no [repositório publico do bower](http://bower.io/search/). Seria possível ter um servidor privado contendo todos estes pacotes dentro da minha infra-estrutura corporativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor solução para isso é o [private-bower](https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower). Está solução irá disponibilizar um servidor HTTP com uma interface gráfica para cadastro dos pacotes privados. Apos a disponibilização do private-bower basta criar um arquivo em seu projeto chamado `.bowerrc` contendo a configuração a seguir:

```
{
  "registry": "http://yourPrivateBowerRepo:5678",
  "timeout": 300000
}
```

Quando fizer a instalação de um novo pacote, o bower irá buscar primeiro em seu servidor privado e depois no servidor publico.

É possível utilizar o private-bower como servidor de cache para os pacotes públicos, tornando o download dos pacotes mais rápido.